# Device used to count number of customers that enter a store

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name of the device used to count the number of *anything* (e.g. the number of people that enter a store)?

I'm thinking of a.. thing.. that fits in the palm of your hand and it has just one button, so that when you click it the number on the screen increments by 1.

Comment: I think there's probably an app for that!

Comment: Reading only the title, I thought of "turnstile" , but it looks like @elliot found the answer you were looking for, the hand-held version.

Comment: "Counter", perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One such mechanical adding machine is a *pascaline* also known as *pascal's calculator*.

**Edit**
You're looking for a *tally counter*.

Comment: I googled it, and that looks way more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @I19 edited. it's a [tally counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_counter).

Answer (score 1):

I've always heard it called a [click counter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FUPSKW), or just a counter.

Normally they have at least two buttons, though. One to reset to zero, one to increment the count.